# What does ")))" mean at the end of a sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Someone I know keeps ending their chat messages with `)))`:

> A: Except if you're not good at jokes
>
> B: Then you can still copy jokes from others.)))

I assume that this isn't some newfangled emoticon gone wrong. What is its purpose?

Comment: what prompted them to say that?

Comment: @Matt: I just pulled one of the messages at random. The conversation was talking about people who were bad at jokes.

Comment: I need to know what prompted the reply so I can tell what emotion they are trying to convey with the emoticon. If they are agreeing with someone it would be a happy face, if they are disagreeing then it would be a sad face.

Comment: @Matt: I added the previous line. The rest of the dialog wasn't terribly relevant.

Comment: Uhm... someone you know?  So why don't you just ask them?

Comment: Maybe they really like this band: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunn_O)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Useful update:

I have been [informed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1466671#1466671) that `)))` is a Russian smiley.

---

Judging from the context it seems that `)))` is equivalent to a `;-)`.

I take it to mean this because the person is making a cheeky remark (about stealing jokes).

Other examples could be:

> Grussus Munbundery: By the way Mr. Smith has a nice english name, what does PtowPtow even mean.
>
> James: That from someone called Grussus Munbundery.)))

---

> A: I really need some help with my French oral
>
> B: That's what she said.)))
>
> C: @B *thwack*

I think that seemingly random punctuation in a sentence is either going to be a mistake or an emoticon. If the character is repeating, it is more likely to be significant. (Unless it's one of those people who love lots of extra fullstops and commas, in which case it's just line noise - the line from their brain to their fingers.)

Comment: In other words, it's some newfangled emoticon gone wrong.)))